# WPF NullRefrence exception within InitializeComponent() method

Tags: wpf

I have a problem with the WPF, Framework 4.0 Profile and Intel HD onboard video cards. The NullReference exception occures in InitializeComponent() method when a new Window is created.

```
    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        InfoPage infoPage = new InfoPage(Owner);
        infoPage.ShowDialog();
    }
```

The exception occures because the infoPage variable is NULL. The behaviour is the same when I am trying to initialize other windows.

The Execute method is called when the user hits the "InfoPage" button. The class containing the execute methods inherited ICommand base class.

```
internal class InfoPageCommand : UICommand
{
    #region Public Methods

    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        InfoPage infoPage = new InfoPage(Owner);
        infoPage.ShowDialog();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: when/where are you calling your Execute function?

Comment: When the user hits the "InfoPage" button - MVVM pattern.

Comment: Is there by any chance an inner exception message? If not, if you go to Debug > Exceptions and turn on Thrown for CLR Exceptions, does it break at some point before you hit the NullReference in InitializeComponent?

Comment: There is no chance for inner exception. What is strange is that the application crashes only on some scenario. The bug can be reproduciable only on several machines in the whole company.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. I turned on the CLR Exceptions as told by @townsean. Then the debug showed where the exception occur (It didn't show the debug point before). It was a `ValueChanged` event handler of a `Slider` control. I was accessing some other controls directly inside its code. Therefore I had to add a null check for those controls.

For me the error started to appear after i changed the default value of the slider. (It seems logical for the event handler to be called when it does).

```
private void slAddRemove_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    if (tbAdd != null && sender.Equals(slAdd))
    {
        tbAdd.Text = slAdd.Value.ToString();
    }

    if (tbRemove != null && sender.Equals(slRemove))
    {
        tbRemove.Text = slRemove.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

After adding the `tbAdd != null` and `tbRemove != null` the error didn't occur.